# Delete Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory

I want to delete an Azure active directory. Sadly I receive error messages.

The first one: "Directory has one or more Azure subscriptions". Yes that's normal, I want to delete everything to start over my Azure account.

[image]

This AD directory just contains one user, which is a global administrator (me with a different email). When I try to modify it to put it as a standard user, I receive this error: "Please try again. If the problem persists, contact support."

[image]

So actually I can't delete this AD directory. I tried to get help from the support but I didn't find a way to have more information.

Do you have an idea of how can I do that? Any help would be appreciated (thanks).

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't the one user in your Azure AD, but the whole AD is tied to your subscription.

You need to create a new Azure AD and connect it to your subscription.

Steps to make this work:

1. Create a new ID
2. go to manage.windowsazure.com
3. select Settings (bottom left menu item
4. Select your subscription
5. Press "Edit Directory" in the bottom navigation bar
6. Associate the new Azure AD

Now you should be able to delete the old Azure AD.

Comment: What if I want to get rid of AD instead of adding a new one?

Comment: Every subscription is tied to an AD, if there is 1 subscription, you need 1 AD. So it is impossible to delete this last AD

Comment: So the first account is already bound to its own AD? My account didn't show any AD-product before I created the "test-domain" ..

Comment: It's hidden by default

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a blog about how to delete Azure AD tenants. Unfortunately you often need to resort to using PowerShell to finally clear out any lingering Principals and/or registered applications.

See https://blog.nicholasrogoff.com/2017/01/20/how-to-delete-an-azure-active-directory-add-tenant/